# Sync Chrome bookmarks to Delicious

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, delicious

I use Google Chrome. I love the snappy and fast feeling. I thought I will miss the add ons of Firefox. But, not really.

However, I used to use [delicious](http://delicious.com/) actively and want to continue to do the same. I miss syncing my bookmarks with delicious.

What is the simplest way to sync Chrome bookmarks with delicious?

Addition:

I see and understand that there are no good "add-ons" per se. I don't mind even a simple cron that I can schedule every day. May be I just have to write one, after all.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also looking for a similar solution.

I used to use Delibar, and am highly considering going back to using it again. I'd love if it was made into a Chrome extension — but since you can customize keyboard shortcuts for various tasks, it may be more preferable since I'm not aware of any extensions that have customizable keyboard shortcuts.

I'd recommend it as an alternative for the time being. The pro version is $10, though.

http://www.delibarapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of add-ons that give you the functionality to add and view the bookmarks from Delicious but struggled to find any that sync with what you *already* have in Chrome.

There is an add-on available for Chrome to [use Delicious](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/75be6f91251f6e0b), but you would then have to manually copy all of your Chrome bookmarks into the Delicious.

There is also a useful [blog article](http://fernandoacorreia.wordpress.com/2008/09/05/delicious-in-google-chrome/) detailing how to add this same simple feature without this add-on, see steps below: (probably the easiest way)

> 1. Open the Delicious bookmarklets help page.
> 2. Press Control+B to show Chrome’s bookmarks bar.
> 3. Still in the Bookmarklets page, locate the instructions for Safari.
> 4. Drag the two links into your bookmarks bar.

I guess sit tight until some bright spark comes up with the perfect add-on to sync what is already in Chrome.  It probably won't be long now that the Chrome guys are finalizing their own sync feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for add-on like functionality, other answers with bookmarklets are just fine and should work.

However if you want to have your delicious bookmarks as part of your bookmark bar, you will have to go couple of steps further.

- Get Developer version of Chrome (don't get scared. 99% of the time it is very stable)
- Get XMarks plugin for Chrome Dev version. (beta version of this plugin is available. Singup is required)
- XMarks allow you to import delicious bookmarks during their setup. see image below.

[image]

Comment: This is no longer available :(

Answer (score 1):

The official Delicious extension is still in beta but it is coming together nicely in my opinion. [Here ya go](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lnejbeiilmbliffhdepeobjemekgdnok).

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar problem. None of the Delicious.com plugins for Chrome will both save the bookmark to Chrome's bookmarks and to Delicious. The ones that say they sync are syncing the bookmarks you set with them, which do not appear in with the regular Chrome bookmarks.

I want to just press the star and have it saved to Delicious. I did find one that did this, though it's a bit rough. [Chromium Delicious plugin by oleg.atamanenko](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/anlkjppofaicbdanhhpbbogknfodfhfm), intercepts the regular Chrome "star" for bookmarking by bringing up the regular Chrome bookmark dialog box briefly, saving it, then brings up a dialog to save to Delicious with suggested tags and the like.

This fits my needs, as I plan to sync my bookmarks directly/manually with Delicious every few weeks so I can get anything I neglect to tag tagged. And I don't use folders for my bookmarks. (And I'm importing my bookmarks into a wordpress install and sorting them by tags...)

I've tried about 6 plugins and this is the only one I found that saved to both delicious and to chrome's bookmarks. I may be incorrect in this conclusion, but that's what I was seeing and what meets my needs best.

Answer (score 1):

Today, [Chromicious](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/animchmhhndbcfahoigdpelodbhnhepg) is all you need.

[image: search bookmarks] [image: preferences]

Answer (score 0):

I finally got something that works.  You pick the tags you want and it puts them into a folder or (i.e. Delicious > tag > links) or directly into your bar.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/delicious-bookmark-bar-sy/agabedjjbijfpccchcmpfpcdfnlpjkoj

I'm content with this and one of the many extensions to add bookmarks :D