# Is there a way to import my bookmarks from Google Chrome to Delicious?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, delicious

My question is not how to [sync chrome bookmarks to delicious](https://superuser.com/questions/27693/sync-chrome-bookmarks-to-delicious), but just how to import my bookmarks to Delicious, so I can stop using Chrome bookmarks.

Is there a way?

*[Chromicious](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/animchmhhndbcfahoigdpelodbhnhepg) is not working, the bookmarks are not showing in Delicious page.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to the Bookmark Manager (Wrench icon -> Bookmarks -> Bookmark manager)
- Choose Organize -> Export, save the file somewhere
- Go to http://export.delicious.com/settings/bookmarks/import
- Upload the file

Comment: Just to say if anyone else stumbles across this like I did - the import/export feature originally found at the link above has been removed - sad face.